# How can I `cabal install` every package on hackage with a custom plugin

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, hackage

I'm working on a custom [ghc plugin](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/compiler-plugins.html).  In order to test it out, I want to run it on every package on hackage.  I'm running into two difficulties with this.

---

First, I need to pass the `-fplugin=MyPlugin` option to ghc when installing packages.  The only way I've found to do this is to create the file `myghc.sh` that contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
ghc -fplugin=MyPlugin $@
```

And then run `cabal install --with-compiler=./myghc.sh`.  But then when I run that command, I get the error

```
Could not find module 'MyPlugin'
it is a member of the hidden package...
```

So is there a special flag I can pass to `cabal install` to use my plugin without having to modify every packages' cabal file?

---

Second, I want my plugin to record information about the package it is compiling, so I need a way for my package to know this information.

It seems like there might be a number of ways to do this, but here's what I've come up with so far.  I want a list of hackage packages ordered so that all the dependencies of a package are guaranteed to come before it in the list?  Then, when I run `cabal install`, I can pass the name of the package it is installing to the plugin.  Since the dependencies are already installed, I wouldn't have to worry about them getting installed under the wrong name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the second part, but the first part should be possible with a command-line flag to cabal:

```
cabal install --ghc-option=-fplugin=MyPlugin
```

Comment: This still gives the `Could not find module ‘MyPlugin’` error message.

Comment: @MikeIzbicki You can ask `cabal` which exact `ghc` command it's running by setting the verbosity high enough. I recommend you try that, then manually play with the ghc invocation yourself until you figure out what needs to change to make it work; then we can work out how to get `cabal` to invoke ghc in the way that works.

Comment: I guess `--ghc-option="-package MyPluginPackage"` *might* work. At least I can't think of a specific reason why it wouldn't work (given that the plugin package is already installed).

Comment: After playing around with cabal sandboxes a bit, I managed to get this to work by passing the `package-id` and `package-db` flags to GHC via `-ghc-option` cabal flag.

Comment: I also managed to get a hacked together solution to the second part by creating a script that recusively calling `cabal install --dry-run`.  It's not very efficient, and doesn't take advantage of cabal's parallelism, but it works.